# the sun shone or the sun was shining

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

I would like to know which one is preferable, or are both possible? It is raining now but this morning the sun was shining brightly or it is raining now but this morning the sun shone brightly.

Comment: **was shining** is the more usual way of *saying* this in conversation; **shone** in this context is in more of a storytelling register. **was shining** suggests that it was bright *throughout* the morning; whereas **shone** doesn't express that ongoing sense and presents something of a *tableau vivant*, a snapshot, if you will.

Comment: shone has essentially become literary.

Comment: @Lambie When  I need to use the past tense of **shine**, I do not hesitate to use  **shone** without feeling that I am using anything but standard English. Do you have any evidence that **shone** has disappeared from colloquial English?

Comment: How can one "prove" anything about how people actually speak every day? I am not  an electrical engineer checking statistics on outages in some database. One can merely give one's personal opinion as a linguist. Also, using words others do not is somewhat specious as an argument.  I would argue, however, that literary English is standard though not all standard language is literary. [NPQ]

Comment: @JeffMorrow I use words all the time that I don't here being used around me.

Comment: @ Lambie Do linguists generally avoid statistical analysis? That was not my impression. I was and am wondering what evidence other than your opinion you can adduce that **shone** has *essentially* disappeared from colloquial English. Ngram actually shows that the frequency of **shone** relative to **was shining** has been increasing. Admittedly, that evidence is from published material so perhaps it is not relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are possible; 'shone' is the simple past tense of the verb 'shine'. We use the simple past about a completed action at a time before now. The sun shone (at some time) this morning.

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/past-simple

'Was shining' is the past continuous, which describes actions or events:

Which continued before and after another action: the sun was shining when I left the house.

Which happened before and after a particular time: it was eight o’clock. The sun was shining.

https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/past-continuous